# Bluetooth device Bose Soundlink Revolve annoyingly turning on automatically at Windows 10 start

Tags: windows, windows-10, audio, bluetooth

I've a bluetooth speaker (the [Bose Soundlink Revolve](https://www.bose.it/it_it/products/speakers/portable_speakers/soundlink_revolve.html)) and it turns on automatically when Windows 10 starts (and Windows 10 bluetooth is ON). It's really annoying.

It does not happen with my mobile or with Ubuntu, so I think it has to do with how Windows 10 manages bluetooth paired devices.

Does anyone know how to set Windows 10 to not turn on paired bluetooth devices automatically? I tinkered a lot with the settings and control panel already...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a feature of the Revolve and its Low Energy Bluetooth. If you press and hold the multifunction button on the device for about 10 seconds (until all the lights flash), the device and its low energy bluetooth will be fully shutdown. Otherwise you will have to disable bluetooth on your laptop to prevent the auto on "feature".

Comment: You saved me from a severe breakdown. Thanks.

Comment: This is such an annoying "feature". Stopped counting the times when the speaker fired up and woke our son... I mean I get the motivation behind it, but Bose needs to make this much more an "easy to find/configure" **optional** setting and not make users search the internet for 15 minutes to figure out what's going on

Comment: Anyway, seemed to work for a while but not anymore. Windows 10 still wakes it up, even if I have used the @paul's trick

Comment: It's so annoying, makes me wanna throw it out of the window and burn it with flame